# How to anchor all the cells on the page in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

To anchor cells in a Google spreadsheet so that you can drag the values/cells/formula, with one or more of the linked cells/values remaining constant you can follow these steps: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zFm4W8t3CR4

But how to do it for many rows and columns?

I'm using data from Google Forms in a spreadsheet and every time someone makes a new input, formulas on another sheet change.

Comment: Sounds strange. What changes in  your formulas?

Comment: So, on first sheet I get results of Google Forms Questionnaire. After new input, it inserts the data in the row below the last answer. Let's say it is the row number 5. On the other sheet I have function that looks at row number 5 and calculates something. After new input that formula is looking at the row number six. It's ok if I make it apsolute reference $A$5 but I have a lot of formulas on that page and I have to manually change. (it's done with cmd + f4 on mac)

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not this is practical may depend on the formulae you are using (which you don’t show) but for something very simple like `=Sum(A1:B2)` you might switch to View, All formulae and replace `(` with `($` and `:` with `:$`.  Then transpose, repeat the process and transpose back. Otherwise “Search using regular expressions” may help.